# Prime faces data table Page Links working rear on click

Tags: html

In IE the pagelinks are highlighting two page numbers at the same time when the user is going from page 1 to page 3. After that it is going back. In chrome it is working fine. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Can you show some relevant HTML code? Without it, this is too vague.

Comment: <p:dataTable id=""
       var=""
       styleClass="datatable-top-margin" pageLinks="5"
       value="#{}"
       widgetVar="facilityStatusAvailableBedWidgetVar" rows="30"
       paginator="true"
       paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
       rowsPerPageTemplate="30" emptyMessage="No records found."
       currentPageReportTemplate="{startRecord} - {endRecord} of {totalRecords}">

Comment: This is what I am using. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: You'd need to show the final HTML, edited into the question.

Comment: Highlighting two page numebrs are happening in IE when we use pageLinks="5" attribute. Otherwise it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

`

```
                        <p:column styleClass="datatable-col-width-five"
                            sortBy="#{facilityStatusAvailableBed.facilityTypeName}"
                            filterStyle="display:none"
                            filterBy="#{facilityStatusAvailableBed.facilityTypeName}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Facility Type" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{facilityStatusAvailableBed.facilityTypeName}" />
                        </p:column>                     

                    </p:dataTable>
```

`

`This is the complete datatable code

Comment: All are dynamic datas and the page is limited to 30 rows . Now this table has 8 pages and i have given the pageLInks="5"